# why I can't convert pointer string to string in Go?

Tags: go

This code parse command-line  arguments. If  I type "/netstat -c /etc/config -I eth0", it should is :" c /etc/config   \n  i eth0",
but it's not . Terminal output is :

c configfile

c interface

```
./netstat -c /etc/config -i eth0
c configfile
c interface
```

Code is as below:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

type CmdSt struct {
    configPtr    string
    interfacePtr string
}

var cmdSt CmdSt

func usage() {

    cmdSt.configPtr = *flag.String("c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
    cmdSt.interfacePtr = *flag.String("i", "interface", "capture network interface")
    /*
        a := flag.String("c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
        b := flag.String("i", "interface", "capture network interface")
    */

    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println("c", cmdSt.configPtr)
    fmt.Println("i", cmdSt.interfacePtr)
    /*
        fmt.Println("c:", *a)
        fmt.Println("i:", *b)
    */
}
func main() {
    usage()

}
```

Comment: Do not post screencasts of text; rather, copy and paste text itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're still holding the default value before `flag.Parse()` is called:

```
// still holding the "configfile" as value
cmdSt.configPtr = *flag.String("c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
// still holding the "interface" as value
cmdSt.interfacePtr = *flag.String("i", "interface", "capture network interface")

// flag is parsed now, but both cmdSt.configPtr and cmdSt.interfacePtr still holding the default value because of the pointer.
flag.Parse()
```

You can solve the problem by using temporary variables:

```
// hold the value to temporary variables
a := flag.String("c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
b := flag.String("i", "interface", "capture network interface")

// parse the flag and save to the variables.
flag.Parse()

// now, point the value to the CmdSt struct
cmdSt.configPtr = *a
cmdSt.interfacePtr = *b


fmt.Println("c", cmdSt.configPtr)
fmt.Println("i", cmdSt.interfacePtr)
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using temporary variables, You can populate your already initialized struct with the flag.StringVar() like below:

```
flag.StringVar(&cmdSt.configPtr, "c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
flag.StringVar(&cmdSt.interfacePtr, "i", "interface", "capture network interface")
```

Then you can call the value immediately.

https://play.golang.org/p/RkW7YKfE8t8

Answer (score 1):

The application dereferences the pointer returned from flag.String after the default is set and before the command line is parsed.  The cmdSt fields are set to the default values as a result.

Fix by using the [flag.xxxVar()](https://godoc.org/flag#StringVar) functions. These functions store flag values into values allocated by the application.

```
flag.StringVar(&cmdSt.configPtr, "c", "configfile", "configure file to parse ")
flag.StringVar(&cmdSt.interfacePtr, "i", "interface", "capture network interface")
flag.Parse()

// cmdSt.configPtr and cmdSt.interfacePtr are now set to
// command flag value or default if the flag was 
// not specified.
```